# ¿Cambiar el texto de un Button con JQuery y volverlo al original?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo un simple archivo y un botón el cual me gustaría que cuando apriete cambie el texto y después de volver a tocar vuelva al anterior texto. Este es mi código html:

Lo que deseo, es cambiar el texto del botón. Que cuando la caja que dice "**Master en JavaScript**" se visualiza, el texto del botón sea "**Cerrar**". Y cuando no se visualice la caja, el texto del botón sea "**Abrir**"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Clase 102 </title>
    <style>

        button{
            width: 200px;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        #caja{
            width: 300px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 5px dashed black;
            background: #ccc;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 50px;
            color: black;
            font-size: 19px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Aprendiendo JQuery Master en JavaScript </h1>
    <button id="todoenuno">
        Cerrar
    </button>
    <div id="caja">
        Master en JavaScript 
    </div>


</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Archivo de js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#todoenuno').click(function(){  
        var that = $(this);

        that.html('Cerrar')

        $('#caja').toggle('fast');
    })
});
```

Intenté dos cosas, una con un If:

```
$('#todoenuno').click(function(){  
    var that = $(this);

    that.html('Cerrar')
    if( that.html() = 'Cerrar'){
        that.html('Abrir')
    }

    $('#caja').toggle('fast');
})
```

Y después lo otro, muy tonto, pero bueno:

```
that.html('Abrir');
that.html('Cerrar');
```

Se que mi consulta es tonta, pero gracias a quienes me ayuden con esta pequeña duda.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que debe cambiar cuando presiones el botón?

Comment: El texto del botón `<button id="todoenuno">
        Abrir
    </button>` Cuando se ve la caja, que diga 'Cerrar', y cuando no se ve la caja que diga 'Abrir'

Comment: Exactamente! Perdón, sí me permites la corrección. Es 'a ver' y no 'haber'. Perdón si te molesta que te corrijan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es tomar el [evento click](https://api.jquery.com/click/), [tomar el contenido](https://api.jquery.com/html/) del botón para [compararlo](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) y después [escribirlo](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
$('#todoenuno').click(function(){//evento click
    var that = $(this);
    var texto = that.html();     //tomar el contenido

    if( texto  == 'Cerrar') {    //comparar el contenido
        that.html('Abrir');      //escribirlo
    }
    else {
        that.html('Cerrar');     //escribirlo
    }
});
```

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias

Comment: no seria mejor usar la funcion togle de jquery?

Comment: Claro, le faltó agregar la función `$('#caja').toggle('fast');` que va después del else. Pero, al menos yo, entendí.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que la tarea es simple y por tanto se puede resolver con JS puro de este modo:

```
<script>
    let boton = document.getElementById("todoenuno")

    boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      (boton.innerText === "Cerrar") ? boton.innerText = "Abrir" : boton.innerText = "Cerrar"
    })
</script>
```

- Obtengo al elemento `button` y lo asigno a una variable
- Le agrego un *listener* al evento click del botón
- Leo la propiedad `innerText` y si su valor es Cerrar entonces lo cambio y le asigno Abrir y si no hago lo contrario